# Iterating through rows in numpy array with one row

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For a 2D numpy array `A`, the loop `for a in A` will loop through all the rows in `A`. This functionality is what I want for my code, but I'm having difficulty with the edge case where `A` only has one row (i.e., is essentially a 1-dimensional array). In this case, the `for` loop treats `A` as a 1D array and iterates through its elements. What I want to instead happen in this case is a natural extension of the 2D case, where the loop retrieves the (single) row in `A`. Is there a way to format the array `A` such that the `for` loop functions like this?

Comment: Can you share a minimal example with the behavior you expect?

Comment: Use `np.atleast_2d` on `A` before iterating.

Comment: I think you needs to differentiate two cases here. If `shape(A) = (1, n)`, i.e., a matrix with a single row, your loop will work just fine. The issue arises if you have a vector, i.e., `shape(A) = (n,)`. You can check `len(shape(A))` beforehand and apply a suitable `reshape` if you only got a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you declare the array yourself you can do this:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Else you can check the `dim` of your array before iterating over it

```
B = np.array([1, 2, 3])
if B.ndim == 1:
    B = B[None, :]
```

Or you can use the function `np.at_least2d`

```
C = np.array([1, 2, 3])
C = np.atleast_2d(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [np.expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to achieve your goal

```
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array trully is a 2D array, even with one row, there is no edge case:

```py
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3]]) 
for line in a:
    print(line)

>>> [1 2 3]
```

You seem to be confusing  `numpy.array([[1, 2, 3]])` which is a 2D array of one line and `numpy.array([1, 2, 3])` which would be a 1D array.